# Do unconscious party members receive experience?

Tags: star-wars-kotor

If my character, or another party member, is knocked unconscious during a fight, do they still receive a share of the experience points if the enemy is killed while they are still unconscious?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

## Yes.

XP is divided evenly amongst all party members, conscious or not. (And in fact, present or not - your companions waiting back on the ship will also level up at the same rate.)

Comment: Excellent. That means my skill-monkey smuggler isn't going to fall behind every time a Sith coughs at him!